# Write a program that generates an integer between 1 and 100 and prompts the user to guess it

Tags: python

> After entering each number
> by the user, the program should report whether the hidden number is greater or
> less. The program should count the number of attempts and after
> how the number is guessed - display the corresponding message.

```
import random

number = int (random.randint (1,100) )
attempts = 0
guess = input ('Guess the value from 1 to 100.')
while guess != number:
    if guess == number:
        print ('Congratulations, you guessed it right!')
    elif guess < number:
        print ('Your guess is less than the number.')
    elif guess > number:
        print ('Your guess is bigger than the number.')
    attempts += 1
    guess = input ('Guess the value from 1 to 100.')

print ('The amount of attempts:', attempts)
```

Comment: Okay. do you have a question? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No need to convert `number` to an `int`, because it's already an `int`.
- You do however need to convert `guess` to an `int` if you want to be able to compare it to `number`!  Note that this will raise a `ValueError` if the user inputs a value that can't be converted to an `int`.
- Make sure to indent the code that goes inside the `while` loop.
- You can make the loop simpler (e.g. no need to assign `guess` before the loop starts) by using `while True:` and just using `break` when it's time to end the loop.

```
import random

number = random.randint(1, 100)
attempts = 0

while True:
    try:
        guess = int(input("Guess the value from 1 to 100."))
    except ValueError:
        print("Try guessing a number.")
        continue
    attempts += 1
    if guess < number:
        print("too low")
    elif guess > number:
        print("too high")
    else:
        print("just right!")
        break

print(f"Total attempts: {attempts}")
```